# In ASP.NET MVC Razor syntax, how do I add a URL Parameter without a value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, hyperlink, query-string, querystringparameter

In Razor syntax, I want to produce a link with a value-less query parameter with `@Html.RouteLink`:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Test", "controller", new { action = "action", this = "value", that = "" })
```

Desired href:

```
https://example.com/controller/action?this=value&that
```

Instead I get:

```
https://example.com/controller/action?this=value
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

QueryString dictionary values are only populated with parameters that have both a name and a value so there is no way you could make it happen with `@Html.RouteLink`.
You can only create the desired link as a string like `https://example.com/controller/action?this=value&that` and here `that` would be keyless value not a valueless parameter key. I advise you to re-think your needs and find a better and more accurate solution.